# Google Visualization Horizontal Axis Labels

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to create a line chart showing the number of hits on a page for an entire year. However I just want the horizontal axis to show one label per month on the first of each month. I've currently got something like this but it only shows the first month.

```
view.setColumns([{
  type: 'string',
  label: 'Month',
  calc: function(dt, row) {
    var date = dt.getValue(row, 0).split('/');
    date = new Date(date[2], date[1] - 1, date[0]);
    var current_month = date.getMonth();
    if (current_month > month || (current_month == 0 && month != 0)) {
      month = current_month;
      return months[month];
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}, 1]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your category values are of the `Date()` type, Google will usually nicely make them display by month by default. See the below example:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Cats');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Rabbits');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(1990, 0, 5), 1, 1, 0.5],
    [new Date(1990, 1, 10), 2, 0.5, 1],
    [new Date(1990, 2, 15), 4, 1, 0.5],
    [new Date(1990, 3, 20), 8, 0.5, 1],
    [new Date(1990, 4, 25), 7, 1, 0.5],
    [new Date(1990, 5, 30), 7, 0.5, 1],
    [new Date(1990, 6, 5), 8, 1, 0.5],
    [new Date(1990, 7, 10), 4, 0.5, 1],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, null);
}
```

If your first column is not stored as a date, and they are just values, then I would suggest converting them to dates instead in order to make Google do the hard work for you.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! I was using google.visualization.arrayToDataTable which doesn't allow dates. Changed it to your format and used date objects made it display much more nicely.

Comment: Glad I could help! Generally speaking, `ArrayToDataTable()` is messier than doing it the above way. By using `DataTable()` you can set up the roles of each column, types, and everything else quite explicitly. You can also create for loops to build a table more easily, and generally have a better time of things. Good luck!